# When is $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}) / \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ formally?

Tags: group-theory

Is the following:
$$(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}) / \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$$

just the informal way of going through the isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the group $$\tilde{\mathbb{Z}} := \{ (z,0) | z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ i.e., formally:

$$(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}) / \tilde{\mathbb{Z}} = \tilde{\mathbb{Z}} \sim \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: It is not true that "$(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z} =\mathbb{Z}$," for two reasons: firstly, because it should be isomorphism, rather than equality, and secondly, because even at the level of isomorphism it is false without specifying *which* subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ you are talking about.

Comment: See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519850/struggling-with-cosets-and-factor-groups-how-is-bbb-z-x-bbb-z-1-1-iso?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: So you mean, for example, that if I'm referring to $\{(z,z) | z \in \mathbb{Z}\} \sim \mathbb{Z}$ then it won't hold (EDIT: it does as in the comment above this), but if it's $\{(z,0) | z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ or $\{(0,z) | z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ then it does?

Comment: For the cyclic subgroup generated by $(1,1)$ it *does* hold, see the duplicate. You can use this for your case, too.

Comment: Right - just saw, thanks. Any obvious counter example I'm missing?

Comment: Oh yes, for $(2,2)$ it is false, for example. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720900/classifying-the-factor-group-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-langle-2-2-ran?noredirect=1&lq=1). You should read these posts a bit.

Comment: Thanks, they did not come up in my search probably due to notation. Will close the question now - sorry for the potential duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $U$ and $V$ are $R-$ modules. Then $U \oplus V$ is an $R-$ module and the map $$\theta :U \rightarrow U \oplus V$$ defined by $$\theta(u)=(u,0)$$ is a monomorphism. Then $(U \oplus V)/\theta(U)$ is isomorphic to $V.$ You would find it informative to read up on split short exact sequences in a beginning book on homological algebra.